# Generate a unique alphanumeric ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My idea is to generate a unique ID for my table Alphanumeric for My table in SQL server So I use Newid function to do that and then I truncate the result to 8 character. My question is with this code I am sure to have a unique ID? Or maybe not here is the code:

```
DECLARE @r varchar(8) 

SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') + n 
FROM (SELECT top 8 CHAR(number) n 
   FROM master..spt_values 
   WHERE type = 'P' AND 
      (number between ascii(0) and ascii(9) 
         OR number between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') 
         OR number between ascii('a') and ascii('z')) 
   ORDER BY newid()) a 

DECLARE @id varchar(10)  
SET @id=CONVERT(varchar(8), @r)  
DECLARE @myid varchar(10) 

SELECT @myid=SUBSTRING(@r,1,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@r,3,3)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@r,6,3)  

PRINT 'Value of @myid is: '+ @myid
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it's easily readable.

Comment: I highly recommend you read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem before doing any reduction of the information in a GUID.

Comment: hi i tiered to do it and it was impossible i don't know why

Comment: I formatted it for readability. OP is not using a substring of newid() value, OP is using newid() to randomize the order of characters picked to build a string.  This will not be guaranteed unique, either.  I guess the edit needs a peer review.

Comment: If you need a unique ID for a table then why not use Identity?

Comment: I second @Blam's comment. If you need a unique ID for a column value then use `IDENTITY`. My guess is from your question that you have a table that is already out there and the ID column is `CHAR(8)` or `VARCHAR(8)`? Because otherwise there is absolutely no reason to have an 8-character alphanumeric identifier. Use `NEWID` *or* create a new table with an `IDENTITY` column and use a stored procedure to insert a dummy value into that table, grab the value of the last identity inserted, and pad it out with alphanumeric characters. Heck, convert it to hex and pad with zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NEWID() produces a v4 GUID. In that GUID scheme, the first 8 bytes can be any hexadecimal digit 0-F and will be composed entirely of randomly-generated data. That's not guaranteed to be unique; in fact no v4 GUID is guaranteed to be unique, it's just that the random bits (112 of 128) can represent one of 5.19 *decillion* numbers, so the odds of any two of them matching in the same system is infinitesimal. With only the first 8 bytes, you'll only have 2^32 combinations, which may still seem like a lot (1 in 4 billion) but by the birthday problem, after a scant 77,000 have been generated you have a 50-50 shot at generating a duplicate.

Comment: and is it possible to generate 8 char code that  have a logic incrementation E.G: AA-AA-AA-01 then AA-BB-CC-02 AA-AA-AA-99 AB-AA-AA-01 ......AB-AA-AA-99 then AC-AA-AA01 ext ext

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bad idea, and you'll have problems inserting more than one row at a time and maintaining unique values.  But, just for fun, here's some code to increment a string with 8 alphanumeric characters (assuming values should run from 0-9, then A-Z):

```
DECLARE @s varchar(20)= '00-0Z-0Z-ZZ'; --INPUT
DECLARE @n char(36) = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
DECLARE @pos tinyint;
SET @s = REPLACE(@s,'-',''); --REMOVE DASHES
SET @pos = LEN(@s);
WHILE @pos > 0
BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@s,@pos,1) = 'Z'
    BEGIN
        SET @s = STUFF(@s,@pos,1,'0');
        SET @pos = @pos - 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @s = STUFF(@s,@pos,1,SUBSTRING(@n,
                                CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@s,@pos,1),@n)+1,1))
        SET @pos = 0
    END

END
SET @s =  SUBSTRING(@s,1,2) + '-' 
        + SUBSTRING(@s,3,2) + '-' 
        + SUBSTRING(@s,5,2) + '-' 
        + SUBSTRING(@s,7,2) -- Replace Dashes

SELECT @s --OUTPUT
```

Comment: thanks for the code but it is not the result that i am searching for,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, SQL server's NewId generates a [GUID (Globally unique identifier)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), which is a 128-bit value commonly presented as a 32-character hexadecimal string.

Being finite, it certainly can't guarantee uniqueness, as there are *only* 2^128 possible values.  But that's a large enough space that collisions are rare.

If you truncate it to 8 characters (I'm assuming you mean 8 characters in the hexadecimal representation), you reduce the likelyhood of uniqueness greatly, as there are 2^32 possible values.

Uniqueness is certainly not guaranteed.

Comment: Just to expand on this...a 128 bit identifier is EXTREMELY unlikely to have a collision. For a 32 bit identifier, you would only need to generate 77,000 of them to get a 50% chance of collision.

Comment: One must also differentiate between a V1 GUID and a V4 GUID. The original GUID scheme used the generating computer's MAC address and the current timestamp to generate the identifier; that is as unique as you can possibly get, since MACs must be unique for networking to work. However, it's a *HUGE* security hole for data to be flying around with a computer's MAC address; only the domain controller of a LAN must know that, and it's easily spoofed if known. V4 GUIDs have random data in all but two bytes; those two bytes identify the specifics of the GUID algorithm used to create it.

Comment: and is it possible to generate 8 char code that  have a logic incrementation E.G: AA-AA-AA-01 then AA-BB-CC-02 AA-AA-AA-99 AB-AA-AA-01 ......AB-AA-AA-99 then AC-AA-AA01 ext ext

Comment: A V1 GUID, if it's still used, is only unique in its entirety; if you only get the first 8 bytes it'll be the first 8 bytes of the computer's MAC address which will be the same for any GUID generated by the same computer.

Comment: @Apocaliptica61 Ofcourse it is "possible to generate 8 char code that have a logic incrementation". You just need to implement it. Oh, wait, you want code handed to you on a silver plate? ;-)

Comment: realy i dont know how to do it by code but i will searsh for it

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION "GEN1_9A_Z" ( start_val varchar2)
   return varchar2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- GEN1_9A_Z generate next unique alphanumeric string with size 3 -- (0..9A..Z) --
                -- Return 0 when error or end (ZZZ). --
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 001,002,..,009,00A,00B,..,00Z,
-- 010,011,..,019,01A,01B,..,01Z,
-- .............................
-- 090,091,..,099,09A,09B,..,09Z,
-- 0A0,0A1,.................,0AZ,
-- 0B0,0B1,.................,0BZ,
-- .............................
-- 0Z0,0Z1,.................,0ZZ,
-- 100,101,.................,10Z,
-- 110,111,.................,11Z,
-- .............................
-- 990,991,.................,99Z,
-- 9A0,9A1,.................,9AZ,
-- .............................
-- 9Z0,9Z1,.................,9ZZ,
-- A00,A01,.................,A0Z,
-- A10,A11,.................,A1Z,
-- .............................
-- A90,A91,.................,A9Z,
-- AA0,AA1,.................,AAZ,
-- AB0,AB1,.................,ABZ,
-- ..............................
-- AZ0,AZ1,.................,AZZ,
-- B00,B01,.................,B0Z,
-- ..............................
-- ..............................
-- ZZ0,ZZ1,.................,ZZZ ---- END!!!

------------------------- generate 46656 unique alphanumeric. ( 000 - ZZZ ) --------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
is 
   start_value varchar2(3);
   return_val  varchar2(3);
begin

if length(start_val) <= 3 then

  start_value := lpad(upper(start_val),3,'0');

  select 
  (case 
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 0 and v3 != '9'                                 then lpad(to_char(start_value+1),3,'0') 
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 0 and v3  = '9'                                 then v1||v2||chr(65) 
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 1 and ASCII(v3) between 65 and 89               then v1||v2||chr(ASCII(v3)+1)
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 1 and v2 != '9' and v3 = 'Z'                    then v1||chr(ASCII(v2)+1)||'0'
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 1 and v2  = '9' and v3 = 'Z'                    then v1||chr(65)||'0'
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 0 and v3 != '9'                                 then v1||v2||chr(ASCII(v3)+1)
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 0 and v3  = '9'                                 then v1||v2||chr(65)
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1 and v3 != 'Z'                                 then v1||v2||chr(ASCII(v3)+1)
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1 and ASCII(v2) between 65 and 89  and v3 = 'Z' then v1||chr(ASCII(v2)+1)||'0'
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1 and v1 != '9' and v2 = 'Z' and v3 = 'Z'       then chr(ASCII(v1)+1)||'0'||'0'
    when p1= 0 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1 and v1  = '9' and v2 = 'Z' and v3 = 'Z'       then chr(65)||'00'
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 0 and v3 != '9'                                 then v1||v2||chr(ASCII(v3)+1)
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 0 and v3  = '9'                                 then v1||v2||chr(65)
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 1 and v3 != 'Z'                                 then v1||v2||chr(ASCII(v3)+1)
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 1 and v2 != '9' and v3 = 'Z'                    then v1||chr(ASCII(v2)+1)||'0'
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 0 and p3 = 1 and v2  = '9' and v3 = 'Z'                    then v1||chr(65)||'0'
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 0 and v3 != '9'                                 then v1||v2||chr(ASCII(v3)+1)
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 0 and v3  = '9'                                 then v1||v2||chr(65) 
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1 and v3 != 'Z'                                 then v1||v2||chr(ASCII(v3)+1)
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1 and v2 != 'Z' and v3 = 'Z'                    then v1||chr(ASCII(v2)+1)||'0' 
    when p1= 1 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1 and v1 != 'Z' and v2 = 'Z' and v3 = 'Z'       then chr(ASCII(v1)+1)||'00'  
    else '0' 
  end)
  into return_val
  from 
      (
      select 
       NVL(LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(substr(start_value,1,1), ' +-.0123456789',' '))),0) p1,
       NVL(LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(substr(start_value,2,1), ' +-.0123456789',' '))),0) p2,
       NVL(LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(substr(start_value,3,1), ' +-.0123456789',' '))),0) p3,
       NVL(substr(start_value,1,1),0) v1,
       NVL(substr(start_value,2,1),0) v2,
       NVL(substr(start_value,3,1),0) v3,
       start_value
        from  dual
  );
else 
    return_val := '0';
end if;
return return_val;
end;
```